# Infinite product representation for $\left(\frac{a-x}{x}\right)$

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate a function of the form
$$\int _{0}^{a}\left(\frac{a-x}{x}\right)\prod _{n=1}^{\infty }f(n,x)dx$$

I want to do this by turning  $$\left(\frac{a-x}{x}\right)$$  into an infinite product itself. That way, I can turn the two products into one, and then integrate it using the integration by parts formula for n terms (from wikipedia):
$$ \left[ \prod_{i=1}^n u_i(x) \right]_a^b \ =\ \sum_{j=1}^n \int_a^b u_j'(x) \prod_{i\neq j}^n u_i(x)$$

So my question is, do you know of any infinite products that equal $$\left(\frac{a-x}{x}\right)$$? Is there any way to find a product for such a function?

(Please note that I do not wish to do the integral any other way, as I want a sum/product as the result because the integral is non elementary and I want to calculate it to an arbitrary level of precision)

I found this product which is equal to the above
$$\frac{1}{x\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1+\left(x+1-a\right)^{2^{n}}\right)}$$
but the problem here is that it is only valid from x=a-2 to a, so it cannot be used for integrating from 0 to a.

Maybe a telescoping product could be used?

Comment: How about $\frac{a-x}{x} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1 + \delta_{n,m}(\frac{a-x}{x} -1) \right)$, where $\delta_{n,m}$ is the Kronecker delta and $m$ is your favourite choice of natural number?

Comment: Using a Taylor series for $f(x)=\log((a-x)/x)$ around some $x_0\in]0,a[$ should yield an infinite product for $e^{f(x)}=(a-x)/x\,.$

Comment: You could also define $f(0,x) = \frac{a-x}{x}$ and proceed to evaluate $\int _{0}^{a}\prod _{n=0}^{\infty }f(n,x)dx$ using the integration by parts identity you provided. This looks much simpler to me than trying to put a factor with each $f(n,x)$, but I don't how your $f$s look. In applying that identity you need to swap the limit from the integral with the limit from the product. I don't know much analysis but I think swapping such limits can be problematic, you should check this before proceeding

Comment: Thank you both.